# How to redirect to a new location via controller where pages are in jquery/angular

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a new hybrid ASP.NET 4.5 MVC application where Angular and JQuery are used to design the frontends(pages), Now I need to redirect to another URL via the controller, how to achieve it..

```
if (loginStatus == "True")
        {
            string _action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            string _controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.    ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Index");
            rc.RedirectToPathResult(_action, _controller);
        }
        else
        {
            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Index");
            // rc.Post();
            string strPathAndQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            string strUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(strPathAndQuery, "/");
            rc.RedirectToPathResult(strUrl);
            //HttpRequest htr = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            //rc.Post();

            rc.RedirectToPathResult(strUrl);
        }
```

and redirect to path method is as below

```
public ActionResult RedirectToPathResult(string action, object cntrl)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(action, cntrl);
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectToPathResult(string url)
    {
       return RedirectToAction(url);
    }
```

i have also tried redirecting using a post method bt that also didn,t work

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
   {

       var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
       response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
       return response;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using Angular's routeProvider? Is it a Single Page Application?

Comment: yes i am using angular route provider and it is a single page app too... and i want to redirect from my c# controller, i.e from server side while validating my controller using my custom attribute..

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is just to inject `$location` into your controller and use it:

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$location) {
   $location.path('/some/new/path');
})
```

Comment: hey thanks there,
bt actually i have to redirect it from c# controller i.e from server side... kindly suggest that way..i am redirecting when i am authenticating a method using custom attribute

Comment: You want to redirect from the server side? AFAIK, there are only 2 ways to do that: 1- do a complete redirect (i.e. new page); 2- make an ajax request that receives the new page (either via a 302 redirect or via the body of the message or a header) and then does `$location` as above

Comment: will you please show some sample codes...i had already tried many like RedirectResult, RedirecttopathResult, Redirect to action bt none of these are actually redirecting...

Comment: added my functionality

Comment: OK, and based on your comments above, you want to keep it a single page app, i.e. no complete redirect. Can you explain further *why* you want to redirect from the server side? Wouldn't knowledge of the paths be all on the client?

Comment: actually it is gonna be a online math portal so i want to redirect the user to home page/ login page if he/she is not loggedin....via the custom authentication done on server side...